# core plot mask limit band with plotArea cornerRadius

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot

I'm currently struggling to mask my limitBand for yAxis.
At the moment it draws over the rounded corners of my plotArea! 
I have setup:

```
[y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:range
                                                      fill:bandFill]];
```

and set `graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.masksToBorder = YES;` but it dosn't mask at all.
If I set the `masksToBounds = YES;` all my labels get also clipped. 
Is there any way to clip/mask the limitband?

Here is how it looks right now:
[image]

Big Thanks to any helpful answer!

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please report it on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

Comment: this issue was fixed in release 1.2. http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=510